# search engine by name and surname

Tags: php, jquery

I have created an auto suggestion search box using php and jquery. The user prompted to insert name and surname to find someone that exists in my database, in a table called user. Table users holds 2 columns, name and surname. My search works fine when you type the name but after pressing space to move and type surname does not give any results. The whole problem seems to appear when pressing space button. Any idea how to fix it?

This is my jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){


$('#search_form_1').keyup(function(){
    var value = $(this).val();

    if(value != ''){
        $('#search_result').show();
        $.post('search_form.php', {value: value}, function(data){
            $('#search_result').html(data);
        }); 

    }else{
        $('#search_result').hide();
    }

});

});
```

And this is my php code:

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['value'])== true && empty($_POST['value']) == false){

$value = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['value']);

$query = mysql_query(" SELECT `surname`, `name` FROM `users` WHERE (`surname` LIKE '$value%' OR `name` LIKE '$value%') OR (`name` LIKE '$value%' OR `surname` LIKE '$value%') ");

    while($run = mysql_fetch_array($query)){

    $surname = $run['surname'];
    $name = $run['name'];
    echo " $surname $name ";

    }
  }
?>
```

Comment: Does the column `name` contain the whole name, surname + last name?

Comment: your 2 where clauses in the () are basically the same you can remove one.  Its because youre not splitting your input to allow for "firstname surname" so its searching for surname as "dave hin" which obviously is never going to match as the surname field will be hinch not dave and the same occurs on the first name field.  You need to check your input for a space, explode on the space and use the exploded parts to search on firstname, surname columns separately.  ofc this causes problems with triple names but first things first

Comment: Try changing your query to "select name + ' ' + surname as fullname from users where fullname like '%$value%'" . When you type space the search is looking for the persons name with space on the end of it, which i would imagine doesn't exist in your database.

Comment: column name contains only the name and column surname contains only the surname

Comment: I have writen it like that:  "select name + ' ' + surname as fullname from users where fullname like '%$value%'"  but get errors...any idea why not working?

Comment: What do the errors say? I'm a little rusty on my MySQL syntax. OK, try select CONCAT(name, ' ', surname) as fullname from users where fullname like '%value%'

Comment: The problem with fullname (CONCAT()) is, that if I start with the surname it won't find anything if fullname will be compared to the complete string in the WHERE clause. There go for double comparison as i wrote. The concat function is nice for returning the full name, but not for comparing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to split the search:

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['value'])== true && empty($_POST['value']) == false){

$value = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['value']);

$name_and_surname = explode(" ", $value);

$name = $name_and_surname[0];
$surname = $name_and_surname[1];

$q = " SELECT `surname`, `name` FROM `users` WHERE (`surname` LIKE '$name%' OR `name` LIKE '$name%') OR (`name` LIKE '$surname%' OR `surname` LIKE '$surname%') ";

// check your query one more time
echo $q;

$query = mysql_query($q);

    while($run = mysql_fetch_array($query)){

    $surname = $run['surname'];
    $name = $run['name'];
    echo " $surname $name ";

    }
  }
```

Comment: it works but know displays all names and surnames of my table at the beginning when typing first the name. It starts to display only the people I want when proceed and typing surname. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Put the where clause to: (surname LIKE '$name%' AND name LIKE '$surname%') OR (surname LIKE '$surname%' AND name LIKE '$name%') as soon as you have a space in your input field

Comment: works perfect, my only problem is that I get a message above results like undefined offset... how I can rid of this? but this messages disapeared when pressing space to proceed with surname. The error message has to do with this line:  $name = $name_and_surname[0]; $surname = $name_and_surname[1];

Comment: i am not sure, what do you mean by undefined offset. as in my answer-post works fine for me.

Comment: I get the message undefined offset for line: $surname = $name_and_surname[1];  any idea how to fix this ?

Comment: found the problem... this should be written like this : $name_and_surname = explode(" ", "$value ");  anyway thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to amend the SQL query, you should just be able to do something like this.

```
select name, surname from users where CONCAT(name, ' ', surname) like '%value%'
```

That will take the first name and last name and put a space between them and then search that.

That means when your user hits the space bar it will still find the user you're looking for.

Comment: finds me sql error syntax when using it, any idea what might be wrong?

Comment: copy and paste it in mysql_query of $query

Answer (score 0):

An edit is not granted so here is the code:

```
$value = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['value']);
$names = explode(" ", $value);

if(count($names)>1){
$name = $names[0];
$surname = $names[1];
  $q = "SELECT surname, name FROM users WHERE (name LIKE '$name%' AND surname LIKE '$surname%') OR (name LIKE '$surname%' AND surname LIKE '$name%')";
}else{
  $q = "SELECT surname, name FROM users WHERE (name LIKE '$value%' OR surname LIKE '$value%')";
}
```